# Efficient way to calculate Smith Normal Form of large integer matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, numerical-linear-algebra, algebraic-graph-theory, smith-normal-form

I am interested in calculating the Smith Normal Form for Laplacian matrices of hypercube graphs. Using the elementary divisors method from SAGE, I was able calculate up to the 11-cube (which has a $2^{11} \times 2^{11}$ Laplacian), but anything more than that is taking too long and giving me a PARI error. Is there a better way to calculate SNF for large integer matrices? I would at least like to calculate up to a $2^{13} \times 2^{13}$ matrix.

Comment: https://linalg.org/linbox-html/smith-form-adaptive_8h.html